# why can't erlang smp use enough cpu cores?

Tags: erlang

i start a erlang smp application,just like this:

Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]

and then i use this code to test the smp function:

```
Fun = fun() ->
    L = lists:seq(0, 1000000),
    F = fun(_I, Acc) ->
        I = util:rand(0,1000000),
        case lists:member(I, Acc) of 
             true -> L1 = lists:delete(I, Acc), 
                     L1 ++ [I];
             _ -> Acc ++ [I]
        end
    end,
    lists:foldr(F, L, L)
end.

P = spawn(Fun).

P1 = spawn(Fun).

P2 = spawn(Fun).
```

in early days,it runs perfect, it use about 300% cpu,and load average about 3.

but after few days, run this codes again, it just use about 100% cpu, and can't use other cores.

is that erlang smp's bug? or just the linux limit??

thank you

Comment: Hard to tell without more information. You should investigate if you really have 3 processes waiting in the run queue. And you should make sure there is enough work to make Erlang use more than a single scheduler. There have been some problems with multiple schedulers, but they usually pertain to NIF use, which your above code does not make use of at all.

Comment: Thanks,that is my test code,and it have 3 processes.I've open the smp,sometimes it works but sometimes it just use a single scheduler and I don't know why.Maybe the VM limits？